# "A good knowledge in English"/"a good knowledge of English"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Any comments on the usage of "a good knowledge *in* English"?

Comment: _A good knowledge of biology in English; a good knowledge of business practices in English_ -- no problem. But knowledge of the language itself is _knowledge of English_.

Comment: "knowledge" is uncountable, so you don't say "a knowledge". Correct: good knowledge of English".

Answer (score 2):

"... of ..."

"Knowledge of a topic" and "have knowledge of boating"

Perhaps "knowledgeable about ..."

And "skilled in carving"

Comment: Perhaps, but why?

Comment: The OED might show you when the current usages started, but you need a forensic linguist to figure out why it ended up this way